# Youtube.com built with?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube

Recently Youtube gives me an option to change its theme. Actually i think youtube launches new theme. 
I was checking its code (Front end). It looks like angular, but i am not sure its angular or something else.

Is this angular code ? if yes then what version it is?

or

its something else?

Thank you for your attention. 
:)

[image]

Comment: Does their code import an Angular library? That's how you would know. I'd bet though that their tools are mostly proprietary.

Comment: They are using a library called Polymer

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They definitely don't use Angular.

They use a custom js "framework", and for navigation and dynamic updates they use something called SPF (Structured Page Fragments):

http://youtube.github.io/spfjs/